# Windows 8 installation - cannot create new partition or locate existing one

Tags: windows-installation, windows-8

I am trying to install Windows 8. I have just bought 2 new corsair 120GB Force 3 SSDs.

I set them up in a raid 0 (striped) configuration. When it came to choosing where to install windows I got the error message - "We couldn't create a new partition or locate and existing one. For more information, see the Setup log files"

I have tried clicking the new button and creating a new partition. I have tried formatting the partition. I have tried clicking the 'load driver' and loading the IRST raid drivers. None of these attempts helped.

Then I deleted the RAID volume and unconfigured the RAID in the BIOS and tried installing Windows 8 on just a single drive. I made all the same attempts without trying to do RAID but I still ran into the exact same error.

What is the solution? Thanks for your help!

[image: install location screenshot 1]
[image: install location screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read your setup log files, might have something to do with raid drivers missing

> $windows.~bt\Sources\Panther

Log location before Setup can access the drive.

> $windows.~bt\Sources\Rollback

Log location when Setup rolls back in the event of a fatal error.

> %WINDIR%\Panther

Log location of Setup actions after disk configuration.

> %WINDIR%\Inf\Setupapi*.log

Used to log Plug and Play device installations.

> %WINDIR%\Memory.dmp

Location of memory dump from bug checks.

> %WINDIR%\Minidump*.dmp

Location of log minidumps from bug checks.

> %WINDIR%\System32\Sysprep\Panther

Location of Sysprep logs.

Comment: Thanks for the help Moab! However I tried again and all of a sudden I was able to create a partition. I don't know what it could have been though, I really don't know how anything was different the final time. But never mind it is working!

Comment: @FunkyFresh84 glad you got it installed.